# Get array elements dynamically based on checkbox checked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

i have the products along with check boxes.if i checked that check box that index value should store in new array(should perform push() operation here),if in case again unchecked that check box means it should perform pop() operation.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Politics"/> Politics<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Movies"/> Movies<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="World "/> World<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Go!" />
```

may be this one is duplicate question for give me sorry

any ideas ?

Comment: and where is your related HTML code... please post that too..

Comment: And the _new array_ is going to be defined where exactly? Is there anything you have tried?

Comment: Sorry for this actually this is not my goal this the heart of my task.... :)

Comment: @dbf i'm very new to this technology up now i didn't try any thing ?

Comment: Being new to _a_ technology is not something you should use as an excuse in every question you ask here. You've mentioned it multiple times on all other questions you've asked so far on SO. If you do not try, how can you learn?

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate post, Please check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MYjRf/

Comment: @dbf yeah boss i tried so many time with different different technologies like JS,Jquery but no use thats why i mentioned like that

Comment: Actually my task is similar to this  http://istockphp.com/demo/deleting-multiple-records/?action=0

Comment: @Nitin Chaurasia Thanks  boss i don't have any idea about this based on your link i can do that....

Comment: @Nitin Chaurasia  this one is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

The products will be posted from form in $_POST['options'] array. Try this.

```
  $products=array();

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])
    {
    if(isset($_POST['options']) && !empty($_POST['options']))
    {
      $products=$_POST['options'];

       print_r($products);

    }
```

}
The array $products will be overwritten everytime form is posted. There is no need for push or pop operations here if I understand your problem correctly.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Politics"/> Politics<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Movies"/> Movies<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="World "/> World<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />
```

Comment: thanks for your responds i going to do this one ...

Comment: why i'm getting this error     ReferenceError: isset is not defined 

if(isset($_POST['options']) && !empty($_POST['options']))

Comment: Try   if($_POST['options'] && !empty($_POST['options']))

Comment: $_POST is not defined i am getting this

Comment: ok. Can you please print the output of this statement here after posting the form:                                                print_r($_REQUEST);                                                      Also please add name to submit button like I did in my answer

Comment: yeah i tried like that also still i'm getting same error message

Comment: @Jhon What is the output of print_r($_REQUEST); ?

Comment: thanks for every thing @ cartina   sorry nothing doing that code i have same error    $_POST is not defined

if($_POST['data'] && !empty($_POST['data']))

Comment: Put print_r($_REQUEST); above everything else at top of the page and paste the output here. To remove the error you mentioned, all form input elements should have name attribute.

Comment: yeah got it i have the problem here $products=array;   if i replace this with $options = Array(); its working for me

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. It should be $products=array(); That is the correct way to define an array.

Answer (score 0):

You're using check-boxes, so you can't just use pop, since they might be unchecked in a different order.

So maybe use jQuery to store a link to the JavaScript object on your DOM check-box object using `.data()`  That way you can match the object later using a for loop and use `.splice()` to remove it from the array.

EDIT 1:
So you want to validate the state of the check-box?

```
if (document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked){
          myarray.push(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your information @Grallen Actually what i'm saying if i checked the check box then only it should store in an array or else no need...

Comment: I think I understand.  Added "Edit 1:" to answer.